# Application error on heroku app

Tags: git, node.js, heroku

I am unsure that questions similar to this would help me. I am posting my question here.

When I tried running heroku app after pushing from Git. I got Application error. I tried understanding from Heroku logs. But I could not solve it. Following is my heroku log :

```
2013-08-22T13:41:39.721111+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by venkateshwaran.selvaraj@gmail.com
2013-08-22T13:41:39.740369+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by venkateshwaran.selvaraj@gmail.com
2013-08-22T13:51:31+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-08-22T13:51:46.559912+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by venkateshwaran.selvaraj@gmail.com
2013-08-22T13:51:46.584043+00:00 heroku[api]: Add PATH config by venkateshwaran.selvaraj@gmail.com
2013-08-22T13:51:46.600930+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by venkateshwaran.selvaraj@gmail.com
2013-08-22T13:51:46.646480+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8435747 by venkateshwaran.selvaraj@gmail.com
2013-08-22T13:51:46.670367+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by venkateshwaran.selvaraj@gmail.com
2013-08-22T13:51:46+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-08-22T13:51:50.333471+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node venkat1.js`
2013-08-22T13:51:51.462059+00:00 app[web.1]: Script: /app/venkat1.js
2013-08-22T13:51:51.462059+00:00 app[web.1]: To: hello.txt
2013-08-22T13:51:51.462059+00:00 app[web.1]: Wrote: A startup is a business built to grow rapidly.
2013-08-22T13:51:52.874576+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-22T13:51:52.876904+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-22T13:51:52.863778+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2013-08-22T13:51:54.448525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node venkat1.js`
2013-08-22T13:51:55.205895+00:00 app[web.1]: Script: /app/venkat1.js
2013-08-22T13:51:55.205895+00:00 app[web.1]: Wrote: A startup is a business built to grow rapidly.
2013-08-22T13:51:55.205895+00:00 app[web.1]: To: hello.txt
2013-08-22T13:51:56.510045+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-22T13:51:56.495030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2013-08-22T13:51:57.488699+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=hidden-caverns-8212.herokuapp.com fwd="182.65.171.54" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-22T13:52:06.605453+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=hidden-caverns-8212.herokuapp.com fwd="182.65.171.54" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-22T13:52:07.142203+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=hidden-caverns-8212.herokuapp.com fwd="182.65.171.54" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

My files are on [Github](https://github.com/Venkateshwaran/vengit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are doing [Homework 1](https://class.coursera.org/startup-001/assignment/view?assignment_id=5) for the Coursera [Startup Engineering](https://www.coursera.org/course/startup) course.

That script is not setup to host a web server. The code you are running is writing the message to hello.txt before closing, which should work on your local computer or AWS instance. You can see the results by inspecting the hello.txt file.

In [Homework 3](https://class.coursera.org/startup-001/assignment/view?assignment_id=8) you will get to the code that creates a web server using the node.js Express framework that you will be able to host on Heroku and visit with your browser.